# Ambiguity in proving the derivative of $e^x$.

Tags: calculus, limits

To prove the derivative of $e^x$ my math book did this
$$\begin{align}{d(e^x)\over dx}&=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h} \tag{1}
\\ &= \lim_{h\to0}e^x \cdot\frac{e^h-1}{h} \tag{2}
\\ &= e^x \cdot \lim_{h\to0} {\left(1+\frac{h}{1!}+\frac{h^2}{2!}...\right)-1\over h} \tag{3}
\\ &=e^x\end{align}$$

---

But from where $\boxed{e^h=\left(1+\frac{h}{1!}+\frac{h^2}{2!}+\frac{h^3}{3!}...\right)}$ this formula came? is it Macalurin Series Expansion? Is it $$f(x)=e^x\\ e^x= f(0)+\frac{x\cdot f'(x)\Big|_{x=0}}{1!}+\frac{x^2\cdot f''(x)\Big|_{x=0}}{2!}+....\infty$$

But I am here to find the derivative of $e^x$ so I don't know $f'(x)$ neither$f''(x),f'''(x)$. So I have to stop in step $(2)$. How is this possible? Where is the ambiguity? And also if above method is not the correct way to derive $d(e^x)\over dx$ then how to derive it from **basics**?

Comment: It depends on how the exponential function was introduced to you. It is often defined using the series expansion, in which case this proof is legitimate (and works even for the complex exponential).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to define the function $f(z) = e^z$, all of which are equivalent and the rest of which can be proved from any single definition.

For instance, some authors will define
$$e^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!} \tag{1}$$
and then prove that this implies
$$e^z = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{z}{n}\right)^n. \tag{2}$$  Other authors might begin with $(2)$ and show that this implies $(1)$.  Still others may define $e$ to be the unique positive real number such that
$$\int_{x=1}^e \frac{1}{x} \, dx = 1 \tag{3}$$
and derive the other properties from this.  Consequently, there is no single definition that precedes all of the other properties.

As such, whether the calculation of the derivative of $e^x$ is circular reasoning depends on how the function is defined.

Comment: It's my first time someone defining e using 3rd definition. Do you have any references?

Comment: @PNDas https://mathworld.wolfram.com/e.html cites it as the defining property.